# HttpWebRequest begun to time out

Tags: c#, timeout, httpwebrequest

Yesterday I was able to send `GET` requests to HTTP device:

```
string urlString = "http://192.168.1.100/........."
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(urlString);
request.Timeout = 1000;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("the_login_name", "the_password");
request.GetResponse().Close();
```

but today these requests time out as if device's host is down, although I am able to send these requests manually from browser and the device responds immediately.

What may happen to `HttpWebRequest`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 5000;
request.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 5000;
```